# Using datetime as a timer stored in JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use `datetime` to subtract from a stored `datetime` value in JSON to see if 2 minutes have passed before a command can be used again. When I use the command, each time the JSON value updates as "0" even tho when I print `currentime` it gives me the value I want to store. I've tried changing `timer[id]["flytimer"] = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - epoch).total_seconds()` to `timer[id]["flytimer"] = 0` but still get the same result

```
try:
    with open("timer.json") as fp:
        timer = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    timer = {}

def save_timer():
    with open("timer.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(timer, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def add_flytimer(user: discord.User, flytimer: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in timer:
        timer[id] = {}
        timer[id]["flytimer"] = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - epoch).total_seconds()
        save_timer()

def get_flytimer(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in timer:
        return timer[id].get("flytimer", 0)
    return 0

def reset_flytimer(user: discord.User, flytimer: int):
    id = user.id
    if id in timer:
        timer[id]["flytimer"] = 0
        print("{} flight timer reset".format(user.name))
        save_timer()


            epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
            currenttime = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - epoch).total_seconds()
            if message.content.startswith('!flight'):
                print(currenttime)
                if get_flytimer is None:
                    add_flytimer(message.author, currenttime)
                    print(currenttime)
                    print(get_flytimer(message.author))
                    await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} takes a flight to NY".format(message.author))
                else:
                    takeflight = currenttime - get_flytimer(message.author)
                    if takeflight >= 120:
                        add_flytimer(message.author,currenttime)
                        print(get_flytimer(message.author))
                        await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} takes a flight to NY".format(message.author))
                    else:
                        await client.send_message(message.channel, "{} you still have {} seconds until the next flight".format(message.author, takeflight))
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? How are those functions being called?

Comment: @DanielRoseman edited code to reflect what I think would work. I didn't call `reset_flytimer` in my code because I am not sure if I need to use it to reset the timer each time it is over 2 minutes or not, or if `add_flytimer` will replace the current time thats stored

Comment: Why not use [`commands.cooldown`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.cooldown) instead?